# Setting up nameservers that can be used on domains

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, nameserver, dns-zone

I have a private server in which I host a few web applications. How I'm currently pointing the domain names I purchased to web applications hosted by IIS in my Win Server 2012 R2 is through setting the A record of the domain in the Domain Registerer panel and pointing directly to the my IP address.

However, I have decided to set up my own nameservers such as `ns1.mysite.com` so that I won't need to do this in the future. What I did was to get the IP of my server, enabling DNS and then:

1- Right clicking the forward zone

2- Type in my domain name (i.e. mysite.com)

3- Leaving dynamic update as disabled

4- Creating two A records pointing to my global IP (www and '')

5- Adding ns1 in Name Servers like ns1.mysite.com

6- Configuring the SOA

Now I have set the nameserver I created on my new domain and I tried to check if it works. I got the following errors:

> Name server ns1.myrealdomain.com (x.x.x.140) not authoritative for newdomain.com.
>
> The name server does not answer authoritatively to queries for the tested domain. This is probably due to misconfiguration, usually the name server is not set up to serve the tested domain.

and also

> Server DNS address could not be found.

I have also waited for quite a long time in case it takes time to update but nothing is working.

I'm quite unsure how exactly I can achieve this.

Comment: Don't do this. Hosted DNS services are dirt cheap and are usually run by people understanding DNS (which is quite complex to get right).

Comment: @Sven: What exactly should I do? I'm a software engineer, I don't have much knowledge over networking. Can you please help me?

Comment: I am helping you by telling you to *not* run your own name service because this is unreliable and unnecessary in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @Sven: Understood, but what exactly do I have to do then? Always use the A record?

Comment: Yes, pointing an A record to your servers IP address is OK in most cases.

Comment: @Sven: That works fine for me, but not if I wanna use my server for commercial purposes such as hosting, etc. That is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the conundrum. Use a commercial DNS host. There are several that offer free service tiers. What you use your web server for (commercial or personal) is immaterial.